# GridAdapter java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask

I have got java.lang.NullPointerException, but I don't know where is problem.

This error was from Google Play Console.

Any idea what is the problem?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at pl.test.griditem.GridAdapter.<init>(GridAdapter.java:33)
at pl.test.griditem.ArticlesGridFragment.methodThatDoesSomethingWhenTaskIsDone(ArticlesGridFragment.java:131)
at pl.test.griditem.ArticlesGridFragment.access$0(ArticlesGridFragment.java:127)
at pl.test.griditem.ArticlesGridFragment$1.onTaskDone(ArticlesGridFragment.java:111)
at pl.test.AsyncDownloadData.onPostExecute(AsyncDownloadData.java:66)
at pl.test.AsyncDownloadData.onPostExecute(AsyncDownloadData.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It is my code:

```
private void methodThatDoesSomethingWhenTaskIsDone(RssFeed rssFeed) {               
        ArrayList<RssItem> items = rssFeed.getRssItems();
        GridAdapter newsGridAdapter = new GridAdapter(getActivity(), items);

        if(gridview != null) {
            gridview.setAdapter(newsGridAdapter);
            gridview.setSelection(list_position);
        }       
    }
```

Comment: The error shows that exception is on line number 33 in GridAdapter class. Can you check the particular line in eclipse?

Comment: Can you show us the code of GridAdapter?

Comment: It is size of items in GridAdapter.

I think sometimes ListArray is null, But I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the rssFeed parameter is coming as null to this method.